# Custom preference title font size is larger than standard preference in android 5

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-5.0-lollipop

My app has custom preference with custom layout and after trying my app on android 5, I noticed that my custom preferences look different (font size, color, padding) than the others. So I thought it would be an easy fix just taking `preference.xml` from android 5 SDK, merging with my changes and placing a new layout to `layout-v21` folder. It fixed padding and color issues, but not size of the title which is bigger.

My custom preference constructor looks like this:

```
public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_seekbar);
}
```

preference_seekbar.xml (just added Seekbar to the original layout):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4" />

        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@android:id/widget_frame"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can notice above that title widget has this original attribute: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` which should make font large, but then there is a question why standard preference title font size is smaller if it uses the same layout (only without seekbar)?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, found the [solution here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar_material.xml).

Although I used `textAppearanceListItem` for the title `TextView` as it seems a better fit to me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/preference_icon_minWidth"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4" />

        <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/preference_widget_width"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <SeekBar android:id="@+android:id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/widget_frame"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That works for me. You should change it in your code too, it was kind of confusing.